# Doubt about ultrasonic and IR sensors

Tags: gazebo-sensor

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,
I've seen in the SDF format, that there are IR sensors, but when I include one in a model, Gazebo gives me an error (Error [SensorManager.cc:151] Unable to create sensor of type[ir]).

How can I create an IR sensor?

And, the next one: to create an Ultrasonic (range) sensor, I need to create a ray sensor as it's parent?

I'm very noob with Gazebo, and still learning, but the tutorial on the web is with a contact sensor and doesn't works for my purposes.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1383/doubt-about-ultrasonic-and-ir-sensors/) by [pablogaralv](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/181/pablogaralv/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) on 2013-02-16**:
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/control_robot/mobile_base_laser has a tutorial that uses a laser sensor. I don't know if the laser can help you, but maybe the tutorial could clarify some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The upcoming version of gazebo (1.9) will have ultrasonic sensor built in.

You can create an IR sensor using a ray sensor, and just use one ray.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0